# Pattern for redirecting on unauthorized vuex actions

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, vue.js, vuex

[Navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html) are perfect for redirecting unauthorized users to a login page, but what does one do to redirect unauthorized vuex actions to a login page?

I can do this easily enough in the vue method where I'm calling the action like so:

```
  if (!this.isLoggedIn) {
    this.$router.push({ name: 'login', query: { comeBack: true } })
    $(`.modal`).modal('hide')
    return
  }
```

But then I'm inserting these 5 lines of code for every component method that requires authorization.

All the solutions I can think of sound hacky, so I'm wondering what the vuex way is:

1. In order to reject it at the vuex action level, I have to pass up the $router instance, and I'm still reusing the 5 lines for each action that requires auth.
2. I can handle this in a utility file, but then I'm handling $router instance in that file.
3. I can use a global vue mixin and call it (a) before making a call and then again (b) when getting a 401 back from the server.

All those seem odd. What vuex way am I missing here?

Comment: Do you search for something like store.watch() https://forum.vuejs.org/t/correct-way-to-use-store-watch-in-vuex/1800/7 ?

Comment: unless i'm missing something, i think store.watch would only work if i was protecting a certain piece (of all of) the store

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [middleware](https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html). Unfortunately, Vuex doesn't have an official way to do middleware.

There is a `subscribeAction()` but that runs after the commit, so does not allow mods to the action. There is also a proposal [Middleware processing between actions and mutation](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/958).

As I see it, we want middleware to be able to do two generic things

- cancel the action
- allow alternative actions to be called

The second is difficult to do without patching `store.dispatch()` or messing with the private property `_actions` after store has been created.

However, to guard an action as you describe, we only need to be able to cancel it.

---

Here is a poor-man's middleware for the [modules pattern](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html) for Vuex store which I prefer.

**store construction from modules**

```js
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    config,
    pages: applyMiddleware(pages),
    measures,
    user,
    loadStatus,
    search
  }
})
```

**applyMiddleware**

```js
const applyMiddleware = function(module) {
  if(module.middlewares) {
    Object.values(module.middlewares).forEach(middlewareFn => {
      Object.keys(module.actions).forEach(actionName => {
        const actionFn = module.actions[actionName]
        module.actions[actionName] = addMiddleware(actionName, actionFn, middlewareFn)
      });
    })
  }
  return module;
}
```

**addMiddleware**

```js
const addMiddleware = function(actionName, actionFn, middlewareFn) {
  return function(context, payload) {
    const resultFn = middlewareFn(actionFn)
    if(resultFn) {
      resultFn(context, payload)
    }
  }
}
```

**defining middleware in the module**

```js
const actions = {
  myAction: (context, payload) => {
    ...
    context.commit('THE_ACTION', payload)
    ...
  },
}

const middlewares = {
  checkAuthMiddleware: (action) => {
    return this.isLoggedIn 
      ? action // if logged-in run this action
      : null;  // otherwise cancel it
  }
}

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions,
  middlewares
}
```

This implementation has module-specific middleware functions, but you could also define them globally and apply to as many modules as applicable.

Comment: interesting! some action->mutation plugin (or official middleware) would be great. thank you for this